# Unable to deploy a Liquidity smart contract directly (without offline signature / forged operation)

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm trying to deploy a contract directly [as specified in Liquidity docs](http://www.liquidity-lang.org/doc/usage/index.html#deploying-a-contract-directly-unsafe), but the CLI fails with:

```
Failure: edsk3gUfUPyBSfrS9CCgmCiQsTCHGkviBDusMxDJstFtojtc1zcpsh is not a valid private key
```

I have tried with a combination of different private keys / sources, without any luck. Does anyone know how to deploy a Liquidity contract without forging a local operation (through the Liquidity CLI).

[Github issue](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/issues/205)